# I got an Error Cannot read property 'map' of undefined" using props in React

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I am quite new to react. I am practicing the pros concept and trying to pass data into a component through props object.
I got an Error : TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined.

I used a top level Component called 'App'and a child Component 'Table'.

I dont know what is wrong in my code.

App.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import Table from './Table'

class App extends React.Component{

   
    render() {
      const characters = [

        {
            name: 'Mouad EL Maamar',
            job: 'Frontend Developer',
    
        },
        {
            name: 'John Doe',
            job: 'Full Stack Developer',
    
        },
        {
            name: 'Zouhair El Jemli',
            job: 'Frontend Developer',
    
        },
    
    ]
      return (
        // eslint-disable-next-line react/jsx-no-comment-textnodes
        <div className="Container">
            <Table charachterData={characters} />
          </div>
         ) 
      }
  
    }
    export default App
```

Table.js:

```
import React from 'react'

const TableHeader = () => { 
    return (
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Job</th>
        </tr>
       </thead> 
     )
    }   

    const TableBody = (props) => {
        const rows = props.characterData.map((row, index) => {
          return (
            <tr key={index}>
              <td>{row.name}</td>
              <td>{row.job}</td>
            </tr>
          )
        })
      
        return <tbody>{rows}</tbody>
      }

class Table extends React.Component{
 
render(){ 
    
// accessing the data using this.props.characterData to retrieve the data
    const {characterData} = this.props
    
    return (
            <table>
                <TableHeader />
                <TableBody characterData={characterData} />   
            </table>
        )
    }
}

export default Table
```

index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App'
import './index.css';


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

Comment: typo - charachterData in TableHeader

Answer (score 0):

There is a small Typo in TableBody , use props.characterData instead